# Safely remove hardware of SD card disables card reader instead of just un-mounting the disk volume

Tags: windows-10

I've been searching literally hours on-end for this *magical line* that uses .bat file, AHK file, or ANY FILE to eject 3 SD-CARD's simultaneously.

There are plenty of 3rd party softwares that do this but All of them disable the drive afterwards and it will not re-mount again **only after rebooting the system**. (even crashing explorer.exe and relaunching it doesn't help)

How do I create a shortcut to make my 3 card readers eject the corresponding sd-cards and will mount back when inserted again

Windows 10 Pro x64

Things I've tried:

- `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll, Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll`
- `USB_Disk_Eject.exe`
- `DriveRemove.exe`
- `Nircmd`
- `USBDview`
- `MountVol: G /D`

and many more, all of which disable the drive after ejection

Comment: Does the manual method of ejecting each of them work?

Comment: Yes, no problem.. Works like charm. I can eject them from start taskbar or from right clicking on SD card drive in windows explorer > Eject. both work no problem

Answer (score -1):

Windows has long had write caching disabled on removable media devices, unless you've intentionally enabled that feature. This means that "safely remove hardware" is not required to maintain file structures on a flash drive or similar medium. If the devices have had the feature enabled, disable them and remove the media when the processes are completed.

Also, you may not have to reboot if you choose to continue to use the method you describe. If you open Device Manager and select the computer icon at the top, then the "refresh" toolbar icon, it will re-register the missing devices.

Comment: The fact that write caching is disabled does not mean it's safe to remove the disk whenever you want.

Comment: I figured it's supposed to be fairly easy since windows explorer has this in it's context menu, so probably a registry line ?